# PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1,

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

when i try to connect the bluetooth using flutter_bluetooth_Serial package i got

```
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Starting discovery
I/BluetoothAdapter(29052): startDiscovery
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Discovered 50:9A:3B:BF:BC:AA
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Discovered 78:02:B7:DA:EE:47
I/ViewRootImpl@8cce0a6[MainActivity](29052): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@8cce0a6[MainActivity](29052): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Connecting to 78:02:B7:DA:EE:47 (id: 1)
I/BluetoothAdapter(29052): cancelDiscovery
I/BluetoothSocket(29052): connect() for device XX:XX:XX:XX:EE:47 called by pid: 29052
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Discovery finished
I/BluetoothAdapter(29052): cancelDiscovery
D/FlutterBluePlugin(29052): Canceling discovery (stream closed)
I/BluetoothAdapter(29052): cancelDiscovery


I/flutter (29052): Cannot connect, exception occured:PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
I/flutter (29052):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:1054)
I/flutter (29052):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:1068)
I/flutter (29052):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:583)
I/flutter (29052):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:57)
I/flutter (29052):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.BluetoothConnection.connect(BluetoothConnection.java:64)
I/flutter (29052):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler.lambda$onMethodCall$4$io-github-edufolly-flutterbluetoothserial-FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCallHandler(FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin.java:1007)
I/flutter (29052):  at io.github.edufolly.flutterbluetoothserial.FlutterBluetoothSerialPlugin$FlutterBluetoothSerialMethodCal
```

Comment: What are you trying to connect ? Because this package does not support connection of a mobile device to another mobile device.

Comment: i try to connect the obd device and any other bluetooth device it returns only this error....i want to connect obdII device please give me the any other solution